# Securing HTML form field from getting viewed by others

Tags: php, html

I am trying to integrate Send Money API from Payza on my PHP website. I have received this form here.

```
<form method="post" action="https://api.payza.com/svc/api.svc/sendmoney">
    <input type="hidden" name="USER" value="shubhamjha1000@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PASSWORD" value="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="10.25" />
    <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="RECEIVEREMAIL" value="hostisia@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="SENDEREMAIL" value="shubhamjha1000@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PURCHASETYPE" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="NOTE" value="Payment for service provided" />
    <input type="hidden" name="TESTMODE" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Money">
  </form>
```

Here I have to enter my username and password. No problem with the username but password is a problem. It can easily be seen by anyone by viewing page source or inspecting element in the browser. What method should I use to make it secure enough to process the transaction without allowing anyone to see the password? This might sound a silly question but please suggest some ideas.

Comment: This just means you have to POST data using this format. You don't need to do it in a html form.

Comment: try `md5` , `Hashing` ` crypt()` and read this  http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.storage.php

Comment: don't forget to salt (and pepper ) your password ;)

Comment: if all the values you know already why you try it storing it in DB?

Comment: Please tell me that's **not** part of Payza's integration code... if so, ditch it and use PayPal (I really never thought I'd say that).

Comment: @CD001 I got it from here https://docs.payza.com/v1.0/reference#sendmoney and I am using Paypal too.. Both payment gatways are needed here.. I have seen many websites processing Instant Payments securely via Payza. I want to do the same. That's why I am trying to integrate this and so I am here..

Comment: @CD001 I remember reading years ago similar examples in PayPal docs as well, but these are just to make an example of data accepted by the server. Often html is an easy way to send a POST request. Not sure about Payza, but I _realy hope_ this is written only as a testing example as well.

Comment: @CD001 In fact, how that we have the link... they say: _You do not need web programming knowledge to get started with Standard Integration — a basic understanding of HTML and web page design is sufficient to create and implement [...]_ and _DO NOT use this script in a live environment_

Comment: What if I put it as a HASHED password with `password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` here? Will that be breakable (becoz it will be seen)?

Comment: @ShubhamJha Your question is too broad to answer, first thing said. We don't know how you get the total amount, what exactly you're trying to do (fixed payment? One time? Or shopping cart?). Anyway, just to make it clear again: this was given in the docs as an example of what POST data the server will accept. It doesn't mean you have to send by an HTML form. You probably won't. You probably will take the value and send this data from your server side. If you're in doubt of any of these subjects, do a research about post requests, and sending post with php with curl or without it.

Comment: I'd not heard of Payza before and I've done payment gateway integrations with PayPal, SagePay, Ingenico (formerly Ogone), WorldPay and Barclaycard SmartPay - and things like this would concern me: https://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/alternatives/payza/ ... think I'd probably give it a wide berth.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to do it on the server side of things.

Submit the minimum amount of information back to your server, and then use something like CURL in PHP, if its installed on your server (see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)to speak to the Payza.

If you look at their own documentation site, they show you an example: https://docs.payza.com/v1.0/reference#api-introduction-guide. Scroll down to section "GetPaymentToken" and you have the option to see the code in C# or PHP

Comment: I have that PHP code but how to implement it to make it work?